# Cannot get neighbouring cell id (android)

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming, cellid

I'm working on a small app that gets information about current and neighboring network base stations cells.

I can get cell_id of my current base station( `isRegistered == true` ), but for all others I get `Int.MAXVALUE`

Any solution how to get neighboring cell ids?

I tried another app with Java code but the result is the same.
There is no other way to get info about network than telephony manager and I have no idea what to do now.

```
        val tel = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        val infos = tel.allCellInfo

        for (i in infos.indices) {


            try {
                val info = infos[i]
                if (info is CellInfoGsm)
                //if GSM connection
                {
                    val identityGsm = info.cellIdentity
                    if(identityGsm.cid != Int.MAX_VALUE && identityGsm.cid != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        cellId = identityGsm.cid

                    val gsm = info.cellSignalStrength

                    if(gsm.asuLevel != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        asuLevel = gsm.asuLevel

                    if(gsm.dbm != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        dbm = gsm.dbm

                    if(gsm.level != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        level = gsm.level

                    if(gsm.timingAdvance != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        timingAdvance = gsm.timingAdvance

                    technogy = "gsm"

                } else if (info is CellInfoLte)
                //if LTE connection
                {
                    val identityLte = info.cellIdentity

                    identityLte.pci
                    if(identityLte.ci != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        cellId = identityLte.ci

                    val lte = info.cellSignalStrength

                    if(lte.asuLevel != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        asuLevel = lte.asuLevel

                    if(lte.dbm != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        dbm = lte.dbm

                    if(lte.level != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        level = lte.level

                    if(lte.timingAdvance != Int.MAX_VALUE )
                        timingAdvance = lte.timingAdvance


                    //LTE stuff
                    if(lte.rsrp != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        rsrp = lte.rsrp

                    if(lte.rsrq != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        rsrq = lte.rsrq

                    if(lte.rssnr != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        rssnr = lte.rssnr

                    technogy = "lte"
                    //call whatever you want from lte / identityLte
                } else if (info is CellInfoWcdma)
                //if WCDMA connection
                {
                    val identityWcdma = info.cellIdentity
                    if(identityWcdma.cid != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        cellId = identityWcdma.cid

                    val wcdma = info.cellSignalStrength

                    if(wcdma.asuLevel != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        asuLevel = wcdma.asuLevel

                    if(wcdma.dbm != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        dbm = wcdma.dbm

                    if(wcdma.level != Int.MAX_VALUE)
                        level = wcdma.level

                    technogy = "wcdma"

                }


                if(cellId != Int.MAX_VALUE){
                    if (info.isRegistered) { //spI'm connected to this cell
                        networkCellInfo.CellId = cellId.toString()
                    }

                    var neighbor = NeighbourCellInfo()
                    neighbor.RSRQ = rsrq
                    neighbor.RSRP = rsrp
                    neighbor.RSSNR = rssnr
                    neighbor.AsuLevel = asuLevel
                    neighbor.Dbm = dbm
                    neighbor.Level = level
                    neighbor.CellId = cellId
                    neighbor.Technology = technogy

                    neihgbors += neighbor

                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG + " cells:", ex.message)
            }

        }
```

We get cell identity and strengths values for each cell, we only need to get `cell_id`.

Comment: It seems that is impossible to get neihgbours id's when LTE or WCDMA is on. When I select **only 2G** as preffered network mode then than cell info is  **CellInfoGsm** type and neighbours cell id is accessible.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Did you find any specifications telling that it's not possible to get ids for LTE / WCDMA, or is it just from experience?

Comment: I didn't find any official documentation, but as I know it's not possible. That confirms me so many sources. If you explore CellInfoLte type and compare with CellInfoGsm type you will find out that Lte type doesn't contain parameter for cell ID.